# <dead_grave> not working on Emacs as it should

Tags: emacs

After setting up AUCTeX with Emacs 24 I experienced the bug described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs-snapshot/+bug/1251176), which is due to my having a not-English keyboard. The XMODIFIERS workaround fixes it, but just to a point; i need to press ` twice, when one should be enough. How can I fix this so that it works properly?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the upcoming Emacs-24.4.  Please test the 24.3.91 pretest to confirm.